# Stop refresh page on form submission by input type image?

Tags: php, html, forms

I have problem that my page refreshes when form is submitted. I have checked other questions on stack but they worked fine when type of input is button like  `<input type="button">` I have also checked javescript and jquery techniques but they doesn't work for me. Kindly can you please guide me that how to stop page refresh on form submission when its type is image.

```
<form action="userOwnProfile.php" method="post">
<input type="image" src="messageicon.jpg">
</form>
```

Comment: When does it "refresh"? Or other way asked, is there anything more? A submit button? Do you press enter? Do you need the form at all?

Comment: Or in other words: if you submit the form, the page will refresh. Or do you want an ajax-call instead?

Comment: I also have ajax call. But it doesn't matter because ajax call is required when you want to get the values from the sql (if I am not wrong). I need form to update the record into sql by pressing image

Comment: But when I click image or submit button it refreshes the page

Comment: Then remove the form, make an ajax-call to `userOwnProfile.php` with the params you need.

Comment: Hi can you please explain or give me some reference to do that

Comment: Hi my record is updated without page refresh because it gets record from other page. But I want to update my record in `userOwnProfile.php`  with the help of form... I can show you code if you need

Comment: Yes, show the code you've got. But consider this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have an id, input name or form name, you don't have a submit button. If you wish to use Ajax you need to identify the element with an id, class or name. What you have cannot work.
Try (add tags)

```
<img id='somename' src='messageicon.png' />
```

Or

```
<button id='somename'>messageicon.png </button>
```

You don't need a form
Then in jquery

```
    $("#somename").click(function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault(); 
    Do something like send data to php 

     });
```